# React Script doesn't start when being launched from root

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, cron

My react app is in the directory `/home/ubuntu/my-app`, the home directory being `/home/ubuntu`. I am using an AWS ec2 instance and I want the react script to execute whenever the server is starting. For this purpose, I wrote the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import time
import shlex, subprocess

time.sleep(20)
args = shlex.split('sudo su ubuntu -c "/usr/bin/npm start --prefix /home/ubuntu/my-app"')
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

When I run the script manually with `./react-start.py` everything works just fine. However, when I reboot the AWS instance, I get the following log:

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /home/ubuntu/my-app
> react-scripts start

^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: Project is running at http://172.31.14.57/
^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: webpack output is served from
^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /home/>
^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

..and nothing happens.

I am using crontab to call the script at reboot by the way. Does anyone have an idea why it's not working? Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to cd into the directory first. sudo su ubuntu && cd /home/ubuntu/my-app && /usr/bin/npm start

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this leads to the exact same result :/